# echo array inside array in order

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this some arrays that look like this,

```
    $array = Array(
    'Homer' => Array
    (
        'id' => 222,
        'size' => 12

    ),
    'Bart' => Array
    (
        'id' => 333,
        'size' => 3
    )
);
```

I would like to echo Homer: id is 222, size is 12

then in the next line echo Bart: id is 333, size is 3 using a foreach loop as key and values.

So i basically want to echo all the Simpsons character names which have their id and size next their names.

I tired this but it printed homer too many times and it even used Bart's id and size at one point.

```
    foreach( $array as $billdate => $date) { 
foreach( $date as $k => $v) {         
    echo $billdate; // Prints Homer and bart
    foreach($array as $innerArray){

foreach($innerArray as $key => $value){
echo "[". $key ."][". $value ."] <br/>";
}}
    }            
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Check This](https://eval.in/474066)

Comment: @Uchiha CHECK THIS is also perfect thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try like this:

```
foreach( $array as $billdate => $date) { 
  echo $billdate.': id is '.$date['id'].', size is '.$date['size'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use so many foreach ,just think your need loop ...

```
foreach( $array as $billdate => $date) { 
    echo $billdate; // Prints Homer and bart

    foreach($date as $key => $value){
        echo "[". $key ."][". $value ."] <br/>";
    }                
}
```